# Create a boost::thread and pass it to a HANDLE

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following code:

```
unsigned long ClassName::fn_StartTesterPresentThread()
{
    // m_hTesterPresent is a HANDLE
    if (m_hTesterPresent == NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwThreadId = 0; 

        m_hTesterPresent = CreateThread(NULL, 0, th_TesterPresent, this, 0, &dwThreadId);
    }

    return ACTION_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `CreateThread` function is Windows-specific, but the code needs to be ported to Linux/non-platform-specific.

I now need a way to create a `boost::thread` and pass it into the `HANDLE m_hTesterPresent`.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
unsigned long Class::fn_StartTesterPresentThread()
{
    if (m_hTesterPresent == NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwThreadId = 0;        

        boost::thread threadTesterPresent(&m_hTesterPresent);
        threadTesterPresent.join();
    }

    return ACTION_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is this the correct way? Sadly, I can't yet compile or test because I still have other parts of the project to port.
Furthermore, the project is a DLL and I don't have the client yet that calls the functions in the DLL.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: you can only compile and test your whole project or nothing?!? Can't you create a small example to test this ([mcve]) ?

Comment: @idclev463035818 No, sadly I cannot. The DLL-functions get call not from a client program, but a ODX Service (thats what we use at my company). This ODX File has yet to be created.

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `boost::thread` should be a function to call, here `th_TesterPresent`.

If you are porting this code to non-Windows environments, I suggest you use typedefs to distinguish between the different kinds of HANDLEs.

Then you can have:

```
#ifndef WINDOWS
  typedef boost::thread* THREAD_HANDLE;
  typedef boost::mutex MUTEX_HANDLE;
#else
  typedef HANDLE THREAD_HANDLE;
  typedef HANDLE MUTEX_HANDLE;
#endif
```

and store THREAD_HANDLE / MUTEX_HANDLE values in various place. Instead of calling OS-specific functions, you can then call generic "createThreadHandle" functions that dispatch to different functions depending on the OS.

Alternatively, you could port your code to an OS-agnostic framework like boost and solve two problems in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into it and see how/if it works.
I don't understand your last sentence though. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Qt has a QThread that is OS-agnostic, while Boost has a boost::thread that works on Windows as well. If you move away from the Windows API towards boost, you get portability cheaply.